# django rest framework - adding to views.obtain_auth_token

Tags: view, overriding, django-rest-framework, http-token-authentication

I have implemented Token Authentication with django rest framework and I can post username and password to `/api-token-auth/` and get the token.

```
url(r'^api-token-auth/', token_views.obtain_auth_token)
```

In addition to the token, I want to get the `User` object related to the returned token.

How can I override/add to this view and also return the actual User object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the relevant view here:

https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authtoken/views.py#L21

Assuming you've created some sort of User serializer already, you can basically take the `user` instance there and shove it into your UserSerializer.  then add it to the response, something like the below.

```
... 
user_serializer = UserSerializer(user)
return Response({'token': token.key, 'user': user_serializer.data})
```